# FullCalendar defaultTimedEventDuration does not work

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to show 45-minute events but I don't get it, they only appear if I put them 50 minutes or more. This is my code:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendar3, {
      ...
      slotEventOverlap: false,
      defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:45',
      slotDuration: '00:15:00',
      slotLabelInterval: '00:45:00',
      ...
});
```

[image: And this is the result]
I need each event to fill 45 minutes.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/PoqJQbp . The events have no end date, so they default to 45 minutes length as per the setting. Please show us the rest of your calendar code, show some sample event data and/or show how you are adding the events to the calendar. We need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What you've shown so far is not enough, by itself, to understand where the problem is coming from. Thanks.

Comment: Also show what and where it fails. Any errors, outputs etc? Expected what, received what ?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. Apparently there was a modification of the size of the events in the CSS code, this was written by another person.
Thank you anyway!